# What's the symbol of INT_MAX, INT_MIN in coffeescript?

Tags: coffeescript

Does coffeescript has such symbols as in c++? In javascript, it seems should be Number.MAX_VALUE. But I didn't find such definition in coffeescript.

Comment: What are you asking? Are you looking for the CoffeeScript version of C and C++'s `INT_MAX` and `INT_MIN`? Have you come across `INT_MAX` and `INT_MIN` in some CoffeeScript and you don't know where they come from?

Comment: @muistooshort sorry, i mean i am looking for the max integer value symbol in coffeescript, just like INT_MAX in c++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

same with one in javascript. you can just use, like [this](http://coffeescript.org/#try:alert%20%22%23%7BNumber.MIN_VALUE%7D%20~%20%23%7BNumber.MAX_VALUE%7D%22)